# how to delete files starting with a date from python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory that contains files with NAME + DATE, example: NAME_DDMMYYYY and I would like to delete all files with dates before that, is that possible?
Today I do this for all files older than 35 days according to the code below:

```
import os
from datetime import date, time, datetime, timedelta


id = 126155
data = date.today().strftime('%d%m%Y')
data2 = datetime.today() - timedelta(days = 35 )
data3 = data2.strftime('%d%m%Y')

list_files = os.listdir(f"C:/Users/{id}/OneDrive/Onedrive - Anderson/")

#DELETE FILE - CBD_0001
for file in list_files:
    if 'CBD_0001_' in file:
        if data3 in file:
            print(f"deleting file: {file}")
            os.remove(file)
```

Comment: *"and I would like to delete all files with dates before that"* Date before what? Can you share example file names and share which of those you would like to delete? It's not clear.

Comment: sorry, I have files named cbd_001_06102022, cbd_001_05102022, cbd_001_04102022 ... and I would like to delete all files with dates before the days declared in the variable data2 (35 days, deleting all files before 01092022)

Comment: `file` is just the filename, `os.remove()` needs the full pathname including the directory. Use `os.path.join()` to combine them.